# Implementing Outbound Voice Calls with AWS Connect in React

Tags: aws-sdk

I'm working on implementing outbound voice calls using AWS Connect in a React application. Currently, I've managed to initiate the call successfully and obtain the ContactId from the response.

I'm seeking guidance on the next steps in implementing the calling functionality based on the AWS Connect documentation. Specifically, I'm looking to:

Retrieve Call Status: How can I check the status of the outbound call, such as whether it's in progress, completed, or failed?

Handle Events: What are the recommended approaches for handling events during the call, such as connecting to an agent, call termination, or encountering errors?

Additional Configuration: Are there any additional configurations or considerations I should be aware of to enhance the functionality or user experience of outbound voice calls?

I've reviewed the AWS Connect documentation, but I would greatly appreciate any insights or code examples from the community to ensure that I'm on the right track.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk"
import React, { useState } from "react"

function IndexPopup() {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("")
  const [isCalling, setIsCalling] = useState(false)
  const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState(null)
  const makeCall = async () => {
    setIsCalling(true)

    try {
      AWS.config.update({
        region: "--region--"
      })

      const connect = new AWS.Connect()

      const response = connect
        .startOutboundVoiceContact({
          DestinationPhoneNumber: phoneNumber,
          ContactFlowId: "--flowId--",
          InstanceId: "--InstanceId--"
        })
        .promise()

      console.log(response)

      setApiResponse(response)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("API call error:", error)
    } finally {
      setIsCalling(false)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={phoneNumber}
        onChange={(event) => setPhoneNumber(event.target.value)}
      />
      <button disabled={isCalling} onClick={makeCall}>
        Call
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IndexPopup
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [amazon-connect-stream](https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams/blob/master/Documentation.md) library to implement Outbound/inbound voice calls on Amazon Connect CCP and there are so many events that you can use to get the [Agent status](https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams/blob/master/Documentation.md#agentsetstate--agentsetstatus) and other details as well. Hope this will help you.